# Refactoring multiple methods into one Generic Method

Tags: c#

I have the following scenario but with 4 methods and calls instead of 2.

```
RemoveNoLongerRequiredFromExceptions(newPeople, masterPeople);
RemoveNoLongerRequiredFromMaster(newPeople, exceptionPeople);

public void RemoveNoLongerRequiredFromMaster(List<NewPerson> newPeople,
  List<MasterPerson> masterPeople)
{
  var noLongerNewPeople = masterPeople.Where(a => !newPeople.Any(b => 
    a.PerId == b.PerId && a.AddressId == b.AddressId));

  foreach (var item in noLongerNewPeople )
  {                
    _masterRepository.DeleteMasterPerson(item.MvpId);
  }            
}

public void RemoveNoLongerRequiredFromExceptions(List<NewPerson> newPeople, 
  List<ExceptionPerson> exceptionPeople)
{
  var noLongerNewPeople = exceptionPeople.Where(a => !newPeople.Any(b => 
    a.PerId == b.PerId && a.AddressId == b.AddressId));

  foreach (var item in noLongerNewPeople )
  {
    _exceptionRepository.DeleteExceptionPerson(item.EvpId);                
  }
}
```

The only thing that is different about the methods is the second input parameter however each of these types have the required properties `PerId` & `AddressId`.

It seems daft having 4 versions of what essentially is the same method but with different models/repos when I know all 4 have the properties and repo methods that I need to call.

I think I need to refactor this using generics but I don't even know where to start.

Using the simple example I've included, how would I refactor the 4 methods into one Generic method?

Comment: Do `MasterPerson` and `ExceptionPerson` have a common base class?

Comment: No they dont, they both have their own interfaces, but that was for DI

Comment: I would make a `Person` common class and use that for `MasterPerson` and `ExceptionPerson`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @ausin wernli:

```
public interface IPerson
{
  int AddressId { get; }
  int PerId { get; }
  int UniqueEntityId { get; }
}

public MasterPerson : IPerson {
  public int UniqueEntityId { get { return MvpId; } }
}
public ExceptionPerson : IPerson {
  public int UniqueEntityId  { get { return EvpId; } }
}
```

However tight coupling between `IPerson` children and repositories might not be what you're after, so you can implement that in manner:

```
public void RemoveNoLongerRequired<T>(List<NewPerson> newPeople,
  List<T> masterPeople) where T : IPerson
{
  var noLongerNewPeople = masterPeople.Where(a => !newPeople.Any(b =>
    a.PerId == b.PerId && a.AddressId == b.AddressId));

  foreach (var item in noLongerNewPeople)
  {
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(MasterPerson))
    {
      _masterRepository.DeleteMasterPerson(item.UniqueEntityId);
      continue;
    }
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(ExceptionPerson))
    {
      _exceptionRepository.DeleteExceptionPerson(item.UniqueEntityId);
      continue;
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: @ondrej-svejdar Error 1 Cannot convert type 'T' to 'PeopleMapping.Repository.Models.ExceptionPerson'

Comment: Is it not a problem that each collection im trying ot use generics for has its own Id, evpId, mvpId, uvpId and emailId, how can it cast T to each and everyone of them when they each have a different Id name

Comment: @SelectDistinct - it is also possible to generalize repositories, however at some point you have to grab list of repositories, let me know if you want to explore that - it would be helpful if you expose how you're creating them.

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar your first item as edit worked, thanks! Can I ask how it is able to cast the generic interface type to each of the 4 different Types seen as the object Id's all have  unique different names? As I write this I see you've changed it again to item.UniqueEntityId, should I use this instead of item as?

Answer (score 1):

You could make an Interface `IPerson` and implement this in both `MasterPerson` as well as `ExceptionPerson`. Define a method such as `DeletePerson(int id)` and this problem becomes trivial.